# In which case will vertical alignment split the image and text into two lines

Tags: html, css

Still not quite sure what is the cause of this issue. I have this html:

```
<button id="AddJudgeBt" type="button" class="positive block">
    <span>Add </span>
    <span class="icon arrows-add icon-add-remove"></span>
</button>
```

I can't paste all the css here because it is spread in all different files and too long. The brief idea is both spans have display: inline-block and the icon one has the image.

[image]

The generated button pretty much looks like this. As you can see, the img and button are splitted into two lines. I tried the margin, padding, position and width of the button and none of them is the issue. Finally I tried to change vertical-alignment from top to text-top and the problem got resolved!

But I am still unclear about what has caused the issue. I tried with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stqgdfcz/1/ But I could not reproduce what has happened.

Can anybody let me know what could be the potential issue?

Comment: add first span display:block;

Comment: it is most possible that the padding left and right values for the button force the icon to flow on the next line.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Tried. It doesn't work

Comment: @KrisD I was thinking about the same thing, too. But I tried to set all the padding/margins of the span and image to be 0 and still doesn't work. So it shouldn't be the padding/margin.

Comment: @LanceShi - i am not referring to the paddings of the span and images, but to the padding applied to your button tag through the id or class.

Comment: @KrisD I hear what you say... But setting the value through developer tool at the element should overwrite everything else... I will try the button and see.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the Image and the text are floating differently. Try floating the image and the text to left, this will align them in the same line and don't forget to clear the float afterwards.
You can do this.

```
img.del {
float:left
}

.astext{
float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying width(may be 50%) and float:left for both SPAN and then adjust margin or padding to align as per the design.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<button><span class="astext">Next</span><span class="aspic"><img src="image/delete1.png" class="del" style="width:10px; height:10px;"  /></span></button>
```

css

```
img.del {

}
.astext {
text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.aspic 
{
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 5%;
}
span {
display:inline-block;
}

button {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 80px;
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stqgdfcz/6/